# Programatically laying out subviews in a stackView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I would like a UITableCell to contain a variable number of buttons, for example "Yes" and "No" buttons, or "Red", "Green" and "Blue" buttons. I've tried various approached but settled on using a vertical stackView within the cell and programmatically adding a view containing the button (feel free to suggest a better approach here).

The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out what auto layout is doing. Normally, when you add views to a stackView in interface builder, you just need a height value and then they stack nicely. However the following code appears to give them a width of zero and if I set the width, the views are all on top of each other. Note this doesn't include the buttons I've mentioned above to make responding easier; I've just added two views.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "formQuestion") as! FormQuestionTableViewCell
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.questionOptions.addSubview(view)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 8)
        // , view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16)
    ])
    let view2 = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.questionOptions.addSubview(view2)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        view2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32)
        // , view2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64)
    ])
    return cell
}
```

And for the sake of completeness, the FormQuestionTableViewCell looks like this...

```
class FormQuestionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var controlContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionOptions: UIStackView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
}
```

This looks like this when the width constraints are enabled (though I believe this shouldn't be necessary)...

[image: AutoLayout problem illustration]

Any help you can give me would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
cell.questionOptions.addSubview(view)
```

When adding a subview to `UIStackView`, you should use:

```
.addArrangedSubview()
```

Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/1616227-addarrangedsubview

Answer (score 1):

You are saying

```
cell.questionOptions.addSubview(view)
```

That's wrong. `questionOptions` is a stack view. If you want it to take responsibility for laying out `view`, you must say

```
cell.questionOptions.addArrangedSubview(view)
```